# MSVC name clash between typedef in template base class and template parameter name

Tags: c++, visual-c++, language-lawyer

Consider this code ([godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/5o6oqGhd5)):

```cpp
template< typename T >
class base
{
private:
    using foo = T;
};

template< typename foo >
class A : public base< foo >
{
public:
    using bar = foo;
};

int main()
{
    A<int> a;
}
```

When compiled with MSVC (tried v19 with `/std:c++17`), I get this error:

```
example.cpp
<source>(12): error C2248: 'base<foo>::foo': cannot access private typedef declared in class 'base<foo>'
        with
        [
            foo=int
        ]
<source>(5): note: see declaration of 'base<foo>::foo'
        with
        [
            foo=int
        ]
<source>(9): note: see declaration of 'base<foo>'
        with
        [
            foo=int
        ]
<source>(17): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'A<int>' being compiled
Compiler returned: 2
```

However, the code compiles fine with state-of-the-art compilers like GCC and Clang, so I assume the code is correct. Is there a workaround for MSVC that would allow me to avoid renaming all affected template parameters in our code base?

Comment: Compile with `/permissive-`

Comment: Or rename the template argument of `A` to something that is distinct to `base::foo`.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Compiling with `/permissive` does not help: https://godbolt.org/z/MW69Y4e1T

Comment: @JakubKlinkovský The `-` after `/permissive` is the important bit. The point is to disable the "permissive" (i.e. non-standard-conforming) behavior.

Comment: Doh! Thanks, I missed that.